# Changing the origin of coordinate in Autodesk Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

When I use section function in my Forge Viewer, camera feel bad. I think it could be because of default origin of coordinate. How can I set origin of the coordinate relative with my loaded and translated *.rvt model?

Answer (score 2):

When you are loading a model using the [loadDocumentNode](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#loaddocumentnode-avdocument-manifestnode-options), you can specify additional loading options in a 3rd parameter to the method call, including a global offset to be applied to all the loaded geometry, for example, like so:

```js
async function loadViewable(viewer, urn, xform /* THREE.Matrix4 */, offset /* THREE.Vector3 */) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        function onDocumentLoadSuccess(doc) {
            const viewable = doc.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry();
            let options = {};
            if (xform) {
                options.placementTransform = xform;
            }
            if (offset) {
                options.globalOffset = offset;
            }
            viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc, viewable, options)
                .then(resolve)
                .catch(reject);
        }
        function onDocumentLoadFailure(code) {
            reject(`Could not load document (${code}).`);
        }
        Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load('urn:' + urn, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);
    });
}
```

Comment: Could you point out where is the documentation of the options parameter, there's no explanation on https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#loaddocumentnode-avdocument-manifestnode-options

Comment: Some of the options are explained in the [loadModel](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#loadModel/) (which is internally called by `loadDocumentNode`) but for some unknown reason, properties like `globalOffset` are not included there.